# Why is there extra whitespace in the second div ("innovating you")?

Tags: html, css

I'm very new to css and html, and realize this might be a silly mistake...

[Code Pen Demo](https://codepen.io/minacosentino/full/JyBQxM)

I don't see a top margin anywhere (using different bootstrap sources and building from them) but no matter how much I dissect the code, I still can't find the problem.

```
<div id="fh5co-products" data-section="products">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 fh5co-section-heading text-center">
    <h2 class="fh5co-lead animate-single product-animate-1">innovating you</h2>
    <p class="fh5co-sub animate-single product-animate-2">Your buyers are constantly evolving, and it can be hard to keep up. That's where we come in. </br>By uncovering the latest trends and best-in-class technologies, we work to ensure that you provide a selling experience that exceeds your buyers' expectations.</p>
```

Comment: There is a 30px margin on the bottom of the jumbotron class.  Since you appear to be overriding the jumbotron class settings, add `margin-bottom:0;` to your settings and it should remove that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add this css in your code

```
.jumbotron {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the first element with a child div `class="jumbotron"` has a property `margin-bottom` with a value of `30px`

in your CSS

```
.jumbotron {
  margin-bottom: 0; // or use margin-bottom: 0 !important if this not work
}
```